# Apply Conditional Formatting if Value comes up more often then comparison value

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have two tables for which i want to conditionally format them.

Table1:

```
|Location|
|Berlin|    (Selected DropDownListItem of Locations)
|Berlin|     
|Hamburg|    
|Munich|     
|Munich|
```

Table2:

```
|Locations|Allowed Number| Used Number|
|Berlin|1|2|
|Hamburg|2|1|
|Munich|2|2|
```

The used Number is automatically generated by checking how often a Location comes up in Table1.

I want to Conditionally Format Table1 so that if the used Number is bigger than the allowed Number, the selected Item has a red background in Table1

How would i do that?

VBA might also work, but the Problem is not everybody might activate the Macros, who uses the Excel Sheet.

Comment: Are both tables in the same worksheet?

Comment: What that "selected item" to have red background would be? The location itself, or another cell where some values are introduced?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with conditional formatting.

Basically, you need a formula to figure out if "Used Number" for a location is larger than "Allowed Number". This can easily be done using `VLookup` two times. Assuming that table2 is a named range, the formula would be something like

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Table2,3,FALSE)>VLOOKUP(A2,Table2,2,FALSE)
```

You can use that formula in a conditional format (*"Use a formula to determine..."*)

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula

```
=SUMIF(C:C,$A1,E:E)>SUMIF($C$2:$C$4,$A1,D:D)
```

[image]